# Why would $f_n(x) = (\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor/2^n)\wedge n$ converge to $f(x)$?

Tags: probability, analysis

Why would $$f_n(x)=\frac{\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor}{2^n}\land n$$

converge to $f(x)$?

I saw this step in the proof of change of variable formula in Rick Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples.

Comment: What does $\wedge n$ mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x)$ in base two. Multiplying by $2^n$ shifts the binary point $n$ places to the right, taking the integer part removes everything to the right of the moved binary point, and dividing by $2^n$ moves the binary point back to its original position. The net effect is to keep only the first $n$ places to the right of the binary point. Clearly, then,

$$\left\langle\frac{\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor}{2^n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$$

converges to $f(x)$. And there is certainly an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(x)<m$, so that taking the minimum with $n$ has no effect when $n\ge m$.

Comment: @WangWeinan: You’re very welcome.

Comment: You meant to say that multiplying by $2^n$ shifts the binary point $n$ places to the right.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. (I’m not really left/right dyslexic: my mental image involves shifting the number, not the point!)